# client-side templated columns for jQuery grid controls in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I need to bind a grid with JSON data obtained through Ajax call using jQuery in ASP.NET MVC application. but for each column, I would like to be able to define a template (similar to the TemplateField in GridView controls in webforms). the template is like a column definition and gives full control over what gets displayed in that column. which grid control supports this? I think jQGrid, DataTable and SlickGrid are the popular jQuery based grid controls for client-side data binding. do any of these support having custom template for one or more columns in the grid? I found a [link](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/14/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx) which shows how to bind JSON data to the grid on the client-side, but no information on how I can define a template for each column.

Answer (score 1):

In jqgrid, you can have a custom formatter function, where you would return the html string template to be used on a given column (http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter).
In Datatable (and jqGrid also), there's an option of creating the grid from an existing  element. In that case, you could create your table using a @foreach statement in razor, and applying your templates inside  cells.

**Example using jqgrid custom formatter and jquery template:**

```
// Your cell template
<script id="MyColumnTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <h1>${Name}</h1>
</script>


<script>

// creating the grid passing the formating function
$('#GridView').jqGrid({
    (...)
    colModel: [         
    { name: 'Custom', formatter: myFormatter}, ...],
     });
});

function myFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
   var data = { Name: 'Test' };
   // applying the jquery template and returning html output
   return $('#MyColumnTemplate').tmpl(data).html();
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I prefer the second option i.e. define the template in razor than in Javascript. but can I do this for client-side binding? I mean can I bind a JSON object collection to the grid in Javascript and still be able to define the grid template in razor? could you share some examples on how to do that? I spent a long time looking for this, but couldn't find anything like that.

Comment: the main reason why I don't want to define my template in Javascript is because it uses string concatenation for HTML and it is very easy to get this wrong and not a clean way to define the template.

Comment: You could create a partial view that defines only the <td> <td/> template, use razor there and retrieve it using an ajax get call. But I think that would be even more complex, so I would recommend using the custom formatter approach.

Comment: You could also choose to hand edit (with jquery) the html output of the grid. In that case, I would recommend Datatable, because it has a much cleaner html output than jqgrid.

Comment: I think you are referring to Ajax helpers (BeginForm and ActionLink), not jQuery. I was asking if I can get the data through an Ajax call using jQuery and still be able to bind the data to the grid by defining the grid column templates in razor. if this is not possible (may not be possible, because razor has C# code and it executes on the server), then it seems I have no other choice except writing HTML in Javascript. I think there is something called JTemplates, can't I use them in this scenario?

Comment: No, I really meant jquery. You could get a partial view of only the <td> cell template, if you really wanted to use razor and don't mind having extra calls to the server. But if you feel comfortable with client side templates, you can avoid extra calls to the server and there are several options you can use, like jquery templates, mustache, etc. You can use them in this cenario because all they do is applying a transformation on a html script and giving you back the html output - the same you would have with string manipulation.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to use the jQuery templates to get the HTML output. can you send me a link to an article that demonstrates this whole scenario or one or more which demonstrate this separately? I will avoid defining template in razor if that means making multiple calls to the server

Comment: Here you will find a complete explanation and examples of using functions as custom formatters: http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/_2kn0mlo1p.htm. 
You need to define a template for your <td></td>, and apply this template from inside your custom formatter function. 
Here is a nice example of using jquery template: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2010/11/20/reducing-code-by-using-jquery-templates.aspx.